# How to reference a class that implements certain interface?

Tags: c#, interface, code-reuse

I have an interface for logging the exceptions, i.e. `IExceptionLogger`.

This interface has 3 implementations: `DBExceptionLogger`, `XMLExceptionLogger`, `CSVExceptionLogger`.

I have an application that will make a use of `DBExceptionLogger`.

The application references only `IExceptionLogger`. How do I create an instance of `DBExceptionLogger` within the application.

I can't reference the `DBExceptionLogger` directly since it will break the purpose of having `IExceptionLogger` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Usage of logger with factory
IExceptionLogger logger = ExceptionLoggerFactory.GetLogger();

public static class ExceptionLoggerFactory
{
  public static IExceptionLogger GetLogger()
  {
    //logic to choose between the different exception loggers
    //e.g.
    if (someCondition)
      return new DBExceptionLogger();
    //else etc etc 
  }
}
```

Comment: Found few articles on factory pattern. Will implement one of my own this afternoon and use suggested code. Thx!

Answer (score 7):

You should look at the concepts of [inversion of control](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FInversion_of_control&ei=nXUPTIqmB5KX4gbXmKnODA&usg=AFQjCNGPpDauWhfjCbf2RPYQQMlADUggbA&sig2=Gc1BesDzGmtvXLoAMgeOkg) and [dependency injection](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDependency_injection&ei=gXUPTKGsBeSU4gaH2ayyDA&usg=AFQjCNHJouKG-tjH2u4lzeyq564prNgdSg&sig2=I2YP1_bRc_Fvq7KDgUXMew). These will help you to inject a particular instance of an object that implements your interface, with your code needing to be aware of exactly what it is beyond that fact. There are many libraries to help you in .NET: Unity, Spring.NET, Autofac, LinFu to name but a few.

Comment: Is this the only way of doing this?  Ideally I don't want to use any non .Net libraries.

Comment: The ones I have mentioned are all .NET libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Factory pattern (a class whose responsibility is creating an `IExceptionLogger` class), or more generally, an Inversion of Control framework.

Answer (score 2):

```
IExceptionLogger logger = new DBExceptionLogger();
```

then pass **logger** variable to all your classes which write logging information.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Poor Man's DI with a static factory like this:

```
public class ExceptionLoggerFactory
{
    public static IExceptionLogger GetDBLogger()
    {
        return new DBExceptionLogger();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private IExceptionLogger _logger;

    public MyClass() : this(ExceptionLoggerFactory.GetDBLogger())
    {

    }

    public MyClass(IExceptionLogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```